# Is there a standard procedure for starting a new FAQ question?

Tags: discussion, meta, etiquette, meta-faq

I was recently investigating into the issue of things that should be removed from posts and was thinking it would be nice to have a FAQ question here on meta to kind of combine them all together. What would be the process for starting a question such as this? Obviously a moderator has to add the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag, but what about creating the actual question? Do you just post it? Is there criteria for how exactly a FAQ question should be layed out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some instructions at the bottom of [the FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites):

> ### Is your question not part of the FAQ?
>
> First look at questions tagged [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) to see if there
>   is a question not in this index that might have the answer you seek.
>   If you still can't find an answer, then see the following instructions
>   for proposing an FAQ question.
>
> #### How can a question be added to this FAQ?
>
> - **Link back** to this index.  Paste this at the end of the
>     question:
>
>   `[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)`
> - Tag as [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) and [support](/questions/tagged/support).  When a post
>     seems to hit a mature state, it will have [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) added by a
>     moderator.
> - Flag for a moderator to mark **community wiki**.  Any FAQ post not
>     yet community wiki should be made into a community wiki.
> - Add a link in the above table of contents.
> - Ask only the question, stated plainly and simply, in the question
>     body. The answer goes in an answer.

Comment: @Arjan Thanks for the notice, but that's deliberate. It's meant as a vague expression of my irritation about harmless posts being deleted. (I had linked a lot of people to the post, and still make use of it occasionally.)

Answer (score 3):

[faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed).

I don't know that's there's a specific format, but the question should be separate from the answer, with both clear and well-laid-out like any other post.